# How to Show/Hide button on same button Click

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want to **Show** and **Hide** ***button1*** when ***button2*** gets clicked.
In my *activity_main.xml*, ***button1*** is set as **GONE**.
I want to set it as **VISIBLE** when ***button2*** gets clicked.
If it is visible, then On Click ***button2*** it will be gone else it will be visible.

Here is my button2 onClickListener

```
     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean button1IsVisible = button1.getVisibility(setVisibility(setVisible(true)));

            if(button1IsVisible){
                button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

How to do that.Help Please .

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean button1IsVisible = button1.getVisibility(setVisibility(setVisible(true)));

            if(button1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `isShown()`

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       if(button1.isShown()) {

       // Your_Staff
        }
        else{
              // Your_Staff
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: 
Declare it

```
    private  boolean button1IsVisible = true;
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            if(button1IsVisible==true)
            {
                    button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    button1IsVisible = false;
            }
            else if(button1IsVisible==false)
            {
                    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button1IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
        });
```

Comment: I think it will not work, in if condition button should gone.

Comment: i had removed == true from your condition, because `if(button1IsVisible)` is same as `if(button1IsVisible==true)`

Comment: @RRR yes i just confused. in visibility and gone

Answer (score 1):

just small change in your code, take `int` instead of `boolean` and change in `if condition`. That's it

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int button1IsVisible = button1.getVisibility();

        if(button1IsVisible==View.VISIBLE){
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

you can use `isShown()` also as described in [IntelliJ Amiya's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34429685/3134215) Answer

Answer (score 1):

Simple, check in onclick of second button that if first button is **`"visible"`**, then change its visibility as "gone", and if it is already **`"Gone"`**, then change it to "visible".

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(button1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: This is what I was Looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(button1.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```